# Assign two lines of output to two different variables in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am writing a Bash script where I have to list the AWS access keys for a user, and then assign them to variables.

A user may have two access keys. So the user will need two variables to store those keys.

This is the line I have so far:

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$user_name" --profile="$aws_key"  | grep -i accesskeyid | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

The output would be something like this:

```
 AKIAJS7KDACQRQ5FJWA
 AKIAICDDTVTMEAB6RM5Q
```

How can I assign each of those to its own variable in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parameter substitution to split the string on a newline. `${variable%$'\n'*}` obtains the portion of the value of `$variable` before the last newline, and `${variable#*$'\n'}` gets the portion after the first newline.

As an aside, Awk generally can do anything `grep` and `sed` can do.

```
variable=$(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$user_name" --profile="$aws_key"  |
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /accesskeyid/{gsub(/\"/,""); print $2}')
```

Comment: `{ read var1; read var2; } <<< "$variable"` might be simpler (or even `{ read var1; read var2; } < <( aws ... | awk '...')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the processing as part of the aws command already, using a `--query`:

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$user_name" --profile="$aws_key" \
    --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].AccessKeyId' --output text
```

returns the IDs in a tab separated line, so you could do something like

```
read -a vars <<< \
    $(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$user_name" --profile="$aws_key" \
    --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].AccessKeyId' --output text)
```

and you get an array `vars` containing your variables.